# handleSubmit from formik is invoked whichever button I click

Tags: reactjs, formik

I want to implement a checking form for validity into the project for ordering food using formik but I have encountered some problems creating two buttons. Whichever button is clicked the handleSubmit is invoked. what can I do to solve this problem?

Function goBack only sets the state to false.

```
export default function Checkout(props) {
  function handleSubmit(event) {
    // event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Hello");
  }

  return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ userName: "Hi", street: "", postalCode: "", city: "" }}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        {(props) => (
          <Form className={styles["form"]}>
            <div className={styles["form-control"]}>
              <div className={styles["form-control__input"]}>
                <label htmlFor="userName">Your name</label>
                <Field type="text" name="userName" id="userName"></Field>
              </div>
              <div className={styles["form-control__input"]}>
                <label htmlFor="street">Street</label>
                <Field type="text" name="street" id="street"></Field>
              </div>
              <div className={styles["form-control__input"]}>
                <label htmlFor="postalCode">Postal code</label>
                <Field type="text" name="postalCode" id="postalCode"></Field>
              </div>
              <div className={styles["form-control__input"]}>
                <label htmlFor="city">City</label>
                <Field type="text" name="city" id="city"></Field>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles["form-actions"]}>
              <CloseButton type="button" onClick={props.goBack}>Back</CloseButton>
              <OrderButton type="submit">Confirm</OrderButton>
            </div>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
  );
}
```

```
export default function CloseButton(props) {
  return <button type={props.type} onClick={props.onClick} className={styles["close-button"]}>{props.children}</button>;
}
```

```
export default function OrderButton(props) {
  return <button type={props.type} onClick={props.onClick} className={styles['order-button']}>{props.children}</button>
}
```

I wanted CloseButton to close the form and go back to the list of orders, but it only invokes handleSubmit created by Formik component instead of the function in the props. I have read the documentation but there is neither anything about creating formik with two buttons nor anything related to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in `props.goBack` you meant to reference the `props` for the component, but instead the `props` from within Formik are being used (as that is the closest block declaration of `props`). Since `goBack` is not defined on the Formik props, you're passing `undefined` as the `onClick` handler to the button.

The most straightforward way to fix this is to rename one of the props variables—I'd suggest naming the Formik ones to `formikProps` or something similar.

A better approach, in my opinion, would be to destructure the props (in both cases, though only one is necessary), like this:

```
export default function Checkout({ goBack }) {
  // ...
  return (
    <Formik>
      {(props) => (
        // ...
        <CloseButton type="button" onClick={goBack}>Back</CloseButton>
        // ...
      )}
    </Formik>
  )
}
```